# Is there a way to check if function is recursive in python?

Tags: python, recursion, python-internals

I want to write a testing function for an exercise, to make sure a function is implemented correctly.
So I got to wonder, is there a way, given a function "foo", to check if it is implemented recursively? 
If it encapsulates a recursive function and uses it it also counts. For example:

```
def foo(n):
    def inner(n):
        #more code
        inner(n-1)
    return inner(n)
```

This should also be considered recursive. 
Note that I want to use an *external* test  function to perform this check. Without altering the original code of the function.

Comment: Let's say you define `foo()` that calls `foo()`.  You then say `bar = foo` and define a new `foo()`.  When you call `bar()`, it calls the other `foo`, not itself.  You might say that the function is recursive because it calls a function that has its name, but it could be a different function with the same name.

Comment: @AlexHall: yet that's the only way to check for recursion in Python, *when it actually is happening*. Because the name used for the recursive call can *at any moment* be rebound to something else.

Comment: @MartijnPieters at the very least a solution for OP's problem can be found that works in most cases. zondo's objection is very specific and doesn't necessarily matter to OP.

Comment: @Arthur.V: the answer is that it cannot be done. It can only be *guessed* at. Static analysis of highly dynamic code is always limited to guessing. The only way to *know* is to trace (which is what the answers in the duplicate do).

Comment: @AlexHall: the objection is not specific; it is fundamental to the question here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't understand how.

Comment: @AlexHall: Any recursive call of the style in this question involves a lookup of a name before calling it. Only if the name references the exact same function from which it is being called, will the call be recursive. The name can be rebound to something else at any point in-between, and Python can't know up-front if and when that would happen.

Comment: @AlexHall: this also means that *any* function that calls something else could potentially be recursive. `lambda s: s.lower()` could be made recursive, by passing in an object whose `lower()` method is that `lambda`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and Arthur V, what do you think of this? http://pastebin.com/Zefbznv5

Comment: @AlexHall: why `exec()` a code template? To avoid rebinding the original name and still get the right globals? Note that you are still executing the code, so the outcome still depends on the exact state at run-time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109314/discussion-between-alex-hall-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: You could do it at runtime by setting recursion limit to say 100 and then running a the function for a value that ought to do 500 recursions; see it fail, and then restore recursion limit and see that it returns the correct value

Comment: You can try the `inspect` module's functions to [retrieve the source code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code) to see if this function is calling itself or not

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution:

```
from bdb import Bdb
import sys

class RecursionDetected(Exception):
    pass

class RecursionDetector(Bdb):
    def do_clear(self, arg):
        pass

    def __init__(self, *args):
        Bdb.__init__(self, *args)
        self.stack = set()

    def user_call(self, frame, argument_list):
        code = frame.f_code
        if code in self.stack:
            raise RecursionDetected
        self.stack.add(code)

    def user_return(self, frame, return_value):
        self.stack.remove(frame.f_code)

def test_recursion(func):
    detector = RecursionDetector()
    detector.set_trace()
    try:
        func()
    except RecursionDetected:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    finally:
        sys.settrace(None)
```

Example usage/tests:

```
def factorial_recursive(x):
    def inner(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        return n * factorial_recursive(n - 1)
    return inner(x)


def factorial_iterative(n):
    product = 1
    for i in xrange(1, n+1):
        product *= i
    return product

assert test_recursion(lambda: factorial_recursive(5))
assert not test_recursion(lambda: factorial_iterative(5))
assert not test_recursion(lambda: map(factorial_iterative, range(5)))
assert factorial_iterative(5) == factorial_recursive(5) == 120
```

Essentially `test_recursion` takes a callable with no arguments, calls it, and returns `True` if at any point during the execution of that callable the same code appeared twice in the stack, `False` otherwise. I think it's possible that it'll turn out this isn't exactly what OP wants. It could be modified easily to test if, say, the same code appears in the stack 10 times at a particular moment.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from inspect import stack

already_called_recursively = False


def test():
    global already_called_recursively
    function_name = stack()[1].function
    if not already_called_recursively:
        already_called_recursively = True
        print(test())  # One recursive call, leads to Recursion Detected!

    if function_name == test.__name__:
        return "Recursion detected!"
    else:
        return "Called from {}".format(function_name)


print(test())  # Not Recursion, "father" name: "<module>"


def xyz():
    print(test())  # Not Recursion, "father" name: "xyz"


xyz()
```

The output is

```
Recursion detected!
Called from <module>
Called from xyz
```

I use the global variable `already_called_recursively` to make sure I only call it once, and as you can see, at the recursion it says "Recursion Detected", since the "father" name is the same as the current function, which means I called it from the same function aka recursion.

The other prints are the module-level call, and the call inside `xyz`.

Hope it helps :D

Comment: but it detects recursion if called from the body of a recursive function... no inspection for that is needed

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet verified for myself if Alex's answer works (though I assume it does, and far better than what I'm about to propose), but if you want something a little simpler (and smaller) than that, you can simply use `sys.getrecursionlimit()` to error it out manually, then check for that within a function. For example, this is what I wrote for a recursion verification of my own:

```
import sys

def is_recursive(function, *args):
  try:
    # Calls the function with arguments
    function(sys.getrecursionlimit()+1, *args)
  # Catches RecursionError instances (means function is recursive)
  except RecursionError:
    return True
  # Catches everything else (may not mean function isn't recursive,
  # but it means we probably have a bug somewhere else in the code)
  except:
    return False
  # Return False if it didn't error out (means function isn't recursive)
  return False
```

While it may be less elegant (and more faulty in some instances), this is *far* smaller than Alex's code and works reasonably well for most instances. The main drawback here is that with this approach, you're making your computer process through every recursion the function goes through until reaching the recursion limit. I suggest temporarily changing the recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit()` while using this code to minimize the time taken to process through the recursions, like so:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(10)
if is_recursive(my_func, ...):
  # do stuff
else:
  # do other stuff
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000) # 1000 is the default recursion limit
```