# i don't know it is dynamic programming

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

i am beginner who learning algorithm in korea college.
it is assignment that solving the problem by using dynamic programming without recursive programming, using only python.
the problem is whether the result  is printed out   'a'  by some operation or not when you input 5 alphabet of string that composed only 'a','b','c'

I made it, but I'm not sure it's dynamic programming
i really appreciate your favor if you give me a advice

Issue.

```
       a b c
     a b b a
     b c b a
     c a c c
```

There is an arithmetic table consisting of three elements, {a, b, and c} and the row, column, and corresponding intersecting values of the table give you a value such as {aa = b, ab = b, ac=a}.

Based on these values, print out whether or not the result can be derived for any string (' possible' or 'impossible'),
 and, if possible, write the calculation sequence using a dynamic programming technique to indicate the sequence through the bracket.

example
input : bbbba.
Result: possible, (b(bb)(bb)a))
In the example above the table are computed by referring to the first round brackets and Analysis,
 (bb) is (b).
Then (b(b)) becomes (b) , and (b)a becomes c, indicating that
 the final requirement of bc=a is met.
- The language must use the Python.
- dynamic programming algorithms are techniques allowed for (dont' use a recursion x).
- Output the first value obtained in many cases
- Set the length of the string, which is the input value, to 5.

```
def rule(x,y):
    if((x=='a' and y=='c') or (x=='b' and y=='c') or (x=='c' and y=='a')):
        return 'a'

    if((x=='a' and y=='a') or (x=='a' and y=='b') or (x=='b' and y=='b')):
        return 'b'

    if((x=='b' and y=='a') or (x=='c' and y=='b') or (x=='c' and y=='c')):
        return 'c'
def rule2(x,y,z):
    return rule(rule(x,y),z)
def rule3(x,y,z):
    return rule(x,rule(y,z))
def rule4(w,x,y,z):
    return rule(rule(w,x),rule(y,z))
def rule5(w,x,y,z):
    return rule(rule2(w,x,y),z)
def rule6(w,x,y,z):
    return rule(rule3(w,x,y),z)
def rule7(w,x,y,z):
    return rule(w,rule2(x,y,z))
def rule8(w,x,y,z):
    return rule(w,rule3(x,y,z))
def rule9(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='((('+v+w+')'+x+')'+y+z+')'
    return rule(rule2(v,w,x),rule(y,z))
def rule10(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='(('+v+'('+w+x+'))('+y+z+'))'
    return rule(rule3(v,w,x),rule(y,z))
def rule11(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='(('+v+w+')(('+x+y+')'+z+'))'
    return rule(rule(v,w),rule2(x,y,z))
def rule12(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='(('+v+w+')('+x+'('+y+z+')))'
    return rule(rule(v,w),rule3(x,y,z))
def rule13(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='((('+v+w+')('+x+y+'))'+z+')'
    return rule(rule4(v,w,x,y),z)
def rule14(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='(((('+v+w+')'+x+')'+y+')'+z+')'
    return rule(rule5(v,w,x,y),z)
def rule15(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='((('+v+'('+w+x+')'+y+')'+z+'))'
    return rule(rule6(v,w,x,y),z)
def rule16(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='('+v+'('+w+'(('+x+y+')'+z+')))'
    return rule(rule7(v,w,x,y),z)
def rule17(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='('+v+'('+w+'('+x+'('+y+z+'))))'
    return rule(rule8(v,w,x,y),z)
def rule18(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='('+v+'(('+w+x+')('+y+z+')))'
    return rule(v,rule4(w,x,y,z))
def rule19(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='(('+v+'(('+w+x+')'+y+')'+z+'))'
    return rule(v,rule5(w,x,y,z))
def rule20(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='('+v+'(('+w+'('+x+y+'))'+z+'))'
    return rule(v,rule6(w,x,y,z))
def rule21(v,w,x,y,z):
    k='('+v+'('+w+'(('+x+y+')'+'))'+z+')'
    return rule(v,rule7(w,x,y,z))
def rule22(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='('+v+'('+w+'('+x+'('+y+z+'))))'
    return rule(v,rule8(w,x,y,z))
def rule23(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='((('+v+w+')'+x+')'+'('+y+z+'))'
    return rule2(rule(v,w),x,rule(y,z))
def rule24(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='(('+v+w+')('+x+'('+y+z+')))'
    return rule3(rule(v,w),x,rule(y,z))

print("     input:",end='')
str=input()
str=list(str)
x=[rule9,rule10,rule11,rule12,rule13,rule14,rule15,rule16,rule17,rule18,rule19,
   rule20,rule21,rule22,rule23,rule24]
for i in range(0,16):
    y=x[i](str[0],str[1],str[2],str[3],str[4])
    if(y=='a'):
        print("possible,",end=' ')
        print(k)
        break
    if(y!='a' and i==15):
        print("impossible")
```

Comment: Please explain the task in more details and give some examples. Also add how dynamic programming has been defined in your course.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right for the site to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). See also: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there can be better way to solve the problem you approached and probably you will learn that once you will see other people assignment solutions, but about recursive/dynamic question you had, your code execution in memory is not recursive.

It is definitely a linear dynamic programming what you have created up there.

Just to be sure, you could also test it via this implementation of a recursive test: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36663046/3564632

So overall you might try with this example just to test it out:

```
from bdb import Bdb
import sys

class RecursionDetected(Exception):
    pass

class RecursionDetector(Bdb):
    def do_clear(self, arg):
        pass

    def __init__(self, *args):
        Bdb.__init__(self, *args)
        self.stack = set()

    def user_call(self, frame, argument_list):
        code = frame.f_code
        if code in self.stack:
            raise RecursionDetected
        self.stack.add(code)

    def user_return(self, frame, return_value):
        self.stack.remove(frame.f_code)

def test_recursion(func):
    detector = RecursionDetector()
    detector.set_trace()
    try:
        func()
    except RecursionDetected:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    finally:
        sys.settrace(None)

def rule(x,y):
    if((x=='a' and y=='c') or (x=='b' and y=='c') or (x=='c' and y=='a')):
        return 'a'

    if((x=='a' and y=='a') or (x=='a' and y=='b') or (x=='b' and y=='b')):
        return 'b'

    if((x=='b' and y=='a') or (x=='c' and y=='b') or (x=='c' and y=='c')):
        return 'c'
def rule2(x,y,z):
    return rule(rule(x,y),z)
def rule3(x,y,z):
    return rule(x,rule(y,z))
def rule4(w,x,y,z):
    return rule(rule(w,x),rule(y,z))
def rule5(w,x,y,z):
    return rule(rule2(w,x,y),z)
def rule6(w,x,y,z):
    return rule(rule3(w,x,y),z)
def rule7(w,x,y,z):
    return rule(w,rule2(x,y,z))
def rule8(w,x,y,z):
    return rule(w,rule3(x,y,z))
def rule9(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='((('+v+w+')'+x+')'+y+z+')'
    return rule(rule2(v,w,x),rule(y,z))
def rule10(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='(('+v+'('+w+x+'))('+y+z+'))'
    return rule(rule3(v,w,x),rule(y,z))
def rule11(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='(('+v+w+')(('+x+y+')'+z+'))'
    return rule(rule(v,w),rule2(x,y,z))
def rule12(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='(('+v+w+')('+x+'('+y+z+')))'
    return rule(rule(v,w),rule3(x,y,z))
def rule13(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='((('+v+w+')('+x+y+'))'+z+')'
    return rule(rule4(v,w,x,y),z)
def rule14(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='(((('+v+w+')'+x+')'+y+')'+z+')'
    return rule(rule5(v,w,x,y),z)
def rule15(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='((('+v+'('+w+x+')'+y+')'+z+'))'
    return rule(rule6(v,w,x,y),z)
def rule16(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='('+v+'('+w+'(('+x+y+')'+z+')))'
    return rule(rule7(v,w,x,y),z)
def rule17(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='('+v+'('+w+'('+x+'('+y+z+'))))'
    return rule(rule8(v,w,x,y),z)
def rule18(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='('+v+'(('+w+x+')('+y+z+')))'
    return rule(v,rule4(w,x,y,z))
def rule19(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='(('+v+'(('+w+x+')'+y+')'+z+'))'
    return rule(v,rule5(w,x,y,z))
def rule20(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='('+v+'(('+w+'('+x+y+'))'+z+'))'
    return rule(v,rule6(w,x,y,z))
def rule21(v,w,x,y,z):
    k='('+v+'('+w+'(('+x+y+')'+'))'+z+')'
    return rule(v,rule7(w,x,y,z))
def rule22(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='('+v+'('+w+'('+x+'('+y+z+'))))'
    return rule(v,rule8(w,x,y,z))
def rule23(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='((('+v+w+')'+x+')'+'('+y+z+'))'
    return rule2(rule(v,w),x,rule(y,z))
def rule24(v,w,x,y,z):
    global k
    k='(('+v+w+')('+x+'('+y+z+')))'
    return rule3(rule(v,w),x,rule(y,z))

print("     input:",end='')
str=input()
str=list(str)
x=[rule9,rule10,rule11,rule12,rule13,rule14,rule15,rule16,rule17,rule18,rule19,
   rule20,rule21,rule22,rule23,rule24]
for i in range(0,16):
    assert not test_recursion(lambda: x[i](str[0],str[1],str[2],str[3],str[4]))
    y = x[i](str[0],str[1],str[2],str[3],str[4])
    if(y=='a'):
        print("possible,",end=' ')
        print(k)
        break
    if(y!='a' and i==15):
        print("impossible")
```